# Python: How pass called in-function variable back to outside function

Tags: python, variables

Below code:
When I call message handling, I have it where if server_handler msg type is "nextValidId", I extract the number 1003 (in the below example) into variable order_id2 within server_handler function.  How do I set order_id = 1003 in main fxn only in the cases where msg type is "nextValidId"; otherwise do nothing.

```
def main():
    order_id = 1001
    tws_conn.registerAll(server_handler)

# here msg text for example is "<nextValidId orderId=1003>"
def server_handler(msg):
    print("Server Msg:", msg.typeName, "-", msg)
    if msg.typeName == "nextValidId":
        order_id2 = int(str(msg).split("nextValidId orderId=",1)[1][:-1])   #returns 1003 for above #example
```

Thank you.

Comment: `if msg_text.startswith('<nextValidId'): `

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to pass values out from a function to the caller:

The most common, obvious and usually best technique is to use  ***return*** statement. The next is to modify the state of some mutable object which has been passed into your function (which might be appropriate to your question here.  (The remaining ways entail modifying global state; almost always a symptom of poor design and coding practices).

```
# here msg text for example is "<nextValidId orderId=1003>"
def server_handler(msg):
    print("Server Msg:", msg.typeName, "-", msg)
    if msg.typeName == "nextValidId":
        order_id2 = int(str(msg).split("nextValidId orderId=",1)[1][:-1])   #returns 1003 for above #example
        msg.nextOrder = orderId. # ??
    return order_id2 # ??
```

Who is calling your *server_handler()* function? How will calls to process this next valid ID be dispatched?